# Selenium Scrape in Python

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

Sorry for the basic question, but I am still trying to learn.  I am trying to figure out a smart way of scraping some stock data with the following HTML, using Selenium2 and Python (multiple `<tr>` of the following on a page):

```
<A NAME="line209"></A><tr align="right" class="odd" nowrap>
<A NAME="line210"></A><td>& </td>
<A NAME="line211"></A><td  align="left"><strong>
<A NAME="line212"></A>BAC US N</strong></td>
<A NAME="line213"></A><td>+</td>
<A NAME="line214"></A><td>17.45</td>
<A NAME="line215"></A><td>17.49</td>
<A NAME="line216"></A><td><strong>17.47</strong></td>
<A NAME="line217"></A><td><strong><font class="fontgreen">
<A NAME="line218"></A>0.14 (0.81%)</font></strong></td>
<A NAME="line219"></A><td>81,974,096</td>
<A NAME="line220"></A><td align="middle"></td>
<A NAME="line221"></A><td>& </td>
<A NAME="line222"></A></tr>
```

Of the above code, I need to extract:

- BAC US N
- +
- 17.45
- 17.49
- 17.47
- 0.14 (0.81%)
- 81,974,096

OK so the following code does what I want it to do.  However in the spirit of learning, I would like to make it much more efficient.  Hope you can help:

```
def getData():
    tickerData=[]
    tickerCounter=0
    ignoreText=['Symbol','T','Bid','Ask','Last',' ','','Change','Volume','FSI','Buy   Sell  ']  
    if quoteType=="Summary":
        numDataPoints=9
    elif quoteType=="Detail":
        numDataPoints=21

    for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'tableStyle2')]"):
        tds=tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        for td in tds:
            if td.text not in ignoreText:
                if len(tickerData) == numDataPoints:
                    insertData(tickerData,tickerCounter)
                    tickerData=[]
                    tickerCounter += 1
                tickerData.append(td.text)                      
    insertData(tickerData,tickerCounter)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: kindly show us what you have tried so far,add that into the question,tell us what problems you are facing?That way people here would willingly help you

Comment: I would first think about the typical format of the stock data you are trying to scrap and go from there. Then and only then will you develop a nice way of extracting the information that you need.

Comment: Do you really need Selenium for this, i.e. do you need to load JavaScript-Content or anything other? Besides that: Load the page in selenium, extract its page-source (via the page_source attribute), and load that html into BeautifulSoup. After that, you can use the findAll-Method/find-Method to parse the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Load that string into a variable called html.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup.findAll('td')
for tag in tags:
    print tag.getText()
```

BeautifulSoup is one of many ways to parse data. You could also use pure Python functions if you understand basic Python by finding the strings "

Comment: Would using BeautifulSoup be any faster or more efficient than my method above?

Comment: Not sure about efficiency. You'd have to time it yourself.